# enrollment error in using microsoft azure api during speaker enrollment

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use MS Azure Speaker recognition API (java) as per https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797 . I am able to get a identificationProfileId. The error occues when I try to enroll. Here is how I am enrolling
- get a wav file of the enrollment audio
- convert to base64 (thru online service)
- attach the base64 it as content to the call for enrollment along with identificationProfileId. I am doubtful about the b64 part

I am getting "Invalid Audio Format: Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header"

I am aware that the service needs the audio in PCM encoding as per doc.

Can someone pls let me know how to convert a wav audio to the required format that can be passed to the enrollment REST endpoint.

```
public class azureApiTest 
{

     public static String getID() 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        String ret = null;

        try
        {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/spid/v1.0/identificationProfiles");


            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "fad541725xxxxxxx3362125790411");


            // Request body

            JsonObject locale = new JsonObject();
            locale.addProperty("locale", "en-us");

            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(locale.toString());
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) 
            {
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                JsonObject o = parser.parse(EntityUtils.toString(entity)).getAsJsonObject();
                ret = o.get("identificationProfileId").getAsString();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            return ret;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try
        {
            String id = azureApiTest.getID();
            System.out.println("ID created = "+id);
            String enrollURL = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/spid/v1.0/identificationProfiles/" +id + "/enroll";
                        System.out.println("enrollURL  = "+enrollURL);

            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(enrollURL);

            builder.setParameter("shortAudio", "true");

            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "fad5417xxxxxxx3362125790411");


            // Request body

            File voiceb64 = new File("/Users/premnair/Desktop/vp/voice1b64.txt");

            String data = FileUtils.readFileToString(voiceb64, "utf-8");
            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(data);
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I pass the file like in the snippet below it works !

```
 File file = new File("/Users/jdoe/Desktop/vp/v5.wav");
 request.setEntity( new FileEntity(file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use base 64, just raw byte array data will work.